# How to sort var length ids (composite string + numeric)?

Tags: mysql, sorting, primary-key

I have a MySQL database whose keys are of this type:

A_10
A_10A
A_10B
A_101
QAb801
QAc5
QAc25
QAd2993

I would like them to sort first by the alpha portion, then by the numeric portion, just like above.  I would like this to be the default sorting of this column.

1) how can I sort as specified above, i.e. write a MySQL function?
2) how can I set this column to use the sorting routine by default?

some constraints that might be helpful: the numeric portion of my ID's never exceeds 100,000.  I use this fact in some javascript code to convert my ID's to strings concatenating the non-numeric portion with the (number + 1,000,000).  (At the time I had not noticed the variations/subparts as above such as A_10A, A_10B, so I'll have to revamp that part of my code.)

Comment: I would suggest making a function that splits up the field in two parts, one alpha and one numeric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to store each part in its own column, and I would strongly recommend to change table structure. If it's impossible, you can try the following:

Create 3 UDFs which returns prefix, numeric part, and postfix of your string. For a better performance they should be native (Mysql, as any other RDMS, is not really good in complex string parsing). Then you can call these functions in `ORDER BY` clause or in trigger body which validates your column. In any case, it will work slower than if you create 3 columns.

Comment: @a1ex07, the main problem is that when calling functions MySQL cannot use an index, which will be a huge draw on speed, much more so than the nativeness of the extraction functions.

Comment: Can't you split your original column into 3 columns?

Comment: Yes sure and then do `order by part1, part2, part3` that would work beautifully and you'll be able to use a (compound) index, speeding things way up.

Comment: @Johan : That is what I said in the very beginning of my answer.

Comment: @a1ex07, I didn't read anything about a compound index, I use them to fake natural sorting.

Comment: @Johan: I meant storing each part in the separate column.

Comment: I probably will split into separate columns, since this seems to be the best route.  thanks.

Comment: @a1ex07: what do you mean "they should be native"?

Comment: Now that I've got 3 parts, is there a way I can associate these columns with the original column so that a request to sort by the ID automatically sorts by the header, number, and subpart?  The reason I'd like this is that I'm dropping data to a javascript data-aware table that is currently  managing getting and sorting queries.  I'm not sure how much coding I'll have to do to take over this library's query submissions.  The end-user should still see (and click sort on) the original ID as if it's a single entity rather than the 3 columns I've split it into.

Comment: You can return concatenated value of 3 new columns to javascript (`SELECT ..., CONCAT(col1,col2,col3) as old_col_name`), so you don't need to change anything on client-side.

Comment: If any of the new columns can be `NULL`, then use `CONCAT_WS` rather than `CONCAT` (`CONCAT` returns `NULL` if any of its arguments is `NULL`)

Answer (score 0):

No simple answer that I know of.  I had something similar a while back but had to use jQuery to sort it. So what I did was first get the output into an javascript array. Then you may want to insert a zero padding to your numbers. Separate the Alpha from Nummerics using a regex, then reassemble the array:

```
var zarr = new Array();

for(var i=0; i<val.length; i++){

    var chunk = val[i].match(/(\d+|[^\d]+)/g).join(',');
    var chunks = chunk.split(",");

    for(var s=0; s<chunks.length; s++){

        if(isNaN(chunks[s]) == true)
            zarr.push(chunks[s]);
        else
            zarr.push(zeroPad(chunks[s], 5));

    }
}

function zeroPad(num,count){ 
var numZeropad = num + '';
while(numZeropad.length < count) {

numZeropad = "0" + numZeropad; 
}
return numZeropad;
}
```

You'll end up with an array like this:

```
A_00100
QAb00801
QAc00005
QAc00025
QAd02993
```

Then you can do a natural sort. I know you may want to do it through straight MySQL but I am not to sure if it does natural sorting.

Good luck!

Comment: MySQL does not have natural sort.

Comment: thanks, codenunter.  the point of using the large number was to zero-pad values without having to write a zeropad function.  however, sorting in javascript is too "after-the-fact" for what I need. I want them to sort nicely for me in my queries before they ever hit a page.  in addition to that, sorting in javascript is too inefficient, especially for the data set sizes.